# Which of the following is correct a) $a^3= e$, $a^4 \neq e$ b) $a^4 \neq e$, $ a^5 \neq e $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let  $G$ be  group  with identity element $e$ such that  for  some  $a \in G$, $a^2 \neq e $ and  $a^6 = e$

Then which  of the  following is correct?

a) $a^3= e$, $a^4 \neq e$

b) $a^4 \neq e$, $a^5 \neq  e $

I think option a) will be true  because  $a^6 = a^3.a^3 = e$ as $a^3= e$ and $a^4 \neq e$

Is it correct?

Please help me

Comment: How can you justify the identity $a^6=a^3$? Why would it be true?
(Actually, it is not true in general. There exists groups with elements of order exactly $6$. For instance, $1$ is of order $6$ in the additive group $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: @ suzet as  i take  $a^6 = a^3.a^3 = 1.e$  where $a^3= 1 $ or  $e$

Comment: But you don't know whether $a^3=e$ or not, right? You only know $a^2 \not =e$ and $a^6 = e$. You may then deduce that $(a^3)^2=e$, but not necessarily that $a^3=e$. Actually, the correct answer is $b)$. Can you see why?

Comment: im not getting  @Suzet  can u explain more

Comment: I am going to write an answer to sum it up then.

Comment: okks  im waiting @ Suzet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me explain why $b)$ is correct.

Generally speaking, given an element $g$ of finite order inside a group, we have, for any integer $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, the following equivalence

$$g^k=e \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{ord}(g)\ \text{divides} \;k$$

where I denote by $\operatorname{ord}(g)$ the order of $g$.

So here, we know that $\operatorname{ord}(a)$ divides $6$, hence $\operatorname{ord}(a)$ is either $1$, $2$, $3$ or $6$.

However, it can not be $1$ nor $2$: it would be in contradiction with the fact that $a^2 \not =e$.

So we know that $\operatorname{ord}(a)$ is either $3$ or $6$. Actually then, in each case, we may see that the statement $b)$ is true. If the order of $a$ is $6$, then of course $a^4$ and $a^5$ can not be equal to $e$ ; and if the order is $3$, then $a^4=a$ and $a^5=a^2$ can not be equal to $e$.

This is why $b)$ is the correct answer.

As for $a)$, in order to prove that in is not true in general, we need to provide a counter example. That is, we need to find a group together with an element $a$ such that $a^2 \not =e$, $a^6 = e$, and ($a^3 \not =e$ OR $a^4 =e$). What lies inside the parenthesis is just the negation of $a)$.

One may see that any element of order $6$ inside a group satisfies these conditions (the proposition inside the parenthesis being satisfied by $a^3 \not = e$).

So the easiest example of a group with an element of order $6$ is, to my opinion, the additive group $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},+)$ with the element $1$. Indeed, we have $2\times 1=2 \not = 0$, we have $6\times 1 = 6 =0$ and we have $3\times 1 = 3 \not = 0$ inside this group.

Comment: thanks  u  Suzets

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Since $a^6=e$, the order of $a$ can be $1$, $2$, $3$ or $6$.

However, since $a^2\ne e$, we can reject the cases where the order is $1$ or $2$.

- Suppose the order is $3$. Then $a^4=a^3a=a\ne e$. Moreover $a^5=a^3a^2=a^2\ne e$. In this case both a) and b) hold.
- Suppose the order is $6$. Then $\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5\}$ are all distinct, in particular, $a^3\ne e$, $a^4\ne e$ and $a^5\ne e$. In this case a) doesn't hold, but b) holds.

Thus the information is insufficient to decide. In a cyclic group of order $3$, both a) and b) hold for a generator of the group.

Answer (score 2):

$a^2a^4 = a^6 = e$. This means that $a^2$ is the inverse of $a^4$. Since $a^2$ is not the identity, $a^4$ isn't either.

From a similar argument, $aa^5 = e$, thus $a^5$ is not identity.